# Indent appendices in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendices

If I use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}

    \section{Some Header}
    ..

    \section{Another Header}
    ..

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

How can I indent the two sections in the table of contents, so the TOC behaves just like `\section{}` and `\subsection{}` with each appendix being indented under the Appendices title just like a subsection would be indented under a section (i.e. same font, the dots between the header and the page number, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really wrong to do stuff like that but here you go.

[image: jamgreenAppendixToc]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
    \subsection{Some Header}
    ..

    \subsection{Another Header}
    ..
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand the warning+answer post. What exactly is behind that warning? Further detail may help solve the issue? Also, does "stuff like that" refer to cast the appendices into subsections? The OP needs their ToC entries to be indented as if they were subsections, but maybe it is not required nor recommended to get them subsection hierarchy.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476157/add-an-indent-to-appendix-line-in-toc-for-included-appendix