# Add an indent to appendix line in ToC for included appendix

Tags: indentation, appendices, include

I asked how to add an indent to a toc line for an appendix [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476128/appendix-appendix-not-in-toc-but-in-header).

In my real structure I am including the appendices:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{MyChapter}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\cftchapindent}{3em}}
\include{appendix_a}
\include{appendix_b}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

But this ends in:

```
Contents

1 My Chapter                      3
Appendices                        5
A One appendix header             7
    B Another appendix header     9
```

The indent does not work for the first include. Is there any solution?

Comment: Whatever you have shared in the MWE part, after compiling that the output is pretty normal.

Comment: For the second appendix, you can try the command `\noindent`

Comment: @SibaMishra But I like to have the indent at the first ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix that by borrowing Martin Scharrer's [`\immaddtocontents`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10297/29873) macro:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[title,toc,page]{appendix}

\makeatletter 
\newcommand\immaddtocontents[1]{{%
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\@writefile{toc}{#1}}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{MyChapter}

\begin{appendices}
\immaddtocontents{\protect\setlength{\cftchapindent}{3em}}
\include{appendix_a}
\include{appendix_b}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]